# How do i grant access to my site only on a node.js heroku app

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, heroku

How can i implement the exports origin-Whitelist "grant access to my site only" on a node.js app.

I  did not write this app [Original git](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/#documentation), i am very new to this and at a (beginner) level.

this is the example code for Whitelisting a site.

> export PORT=8080
>
> export
>   WHITELIST=https://example.com,http://example.com,http://example.com:8080
>
> node server.js

I think that it needs to go in the "**server.js**" file but i am not sure where, how, Or if it should be in separate "JS" file.

Please try to provide a visual & detailed antsier if possible a jsfiddle working example too.

**Update** 
I tried to copy and paste the two first lines to "**server.js**" ended up with an error

```
C:\my-app>heroku local
[WARN] No ENV file found
15:00:20 web.1   |  C:\my-app\server.js:6
15:00:20 web.1   |  export PORT=8080
15:00:20 web.1   |  ^^^^^^
15:00:20 web.1   |  SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
15:00:20 web.1   |      at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
15:00:20 web.1   |      at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
15:00:20 web.1   |      at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
15:00:20 web.1   |      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
15:00:20 web.1   |      at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
15:00:20 web.1   |      at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
15:00:20 web.1   |      at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
15:00:20 web.1   |      at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
15:00:20 web.1   |      at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
15:00:20 web.1   |      at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
15:00:20 web.1   Exited with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

use express.js and cors. they have a very simple example with heroku
https://github.com/expressjs/cors

Comment: Hello Gonzo and thank you for replying, i am unable to find "express.js" in the git you mentioned there are a lot of js files i am not sure which one to use or how.   by the way it is not more simple but it is more detailed.